# Entering UK as British citizen on Australian passport (no British passport)

Tags: visas, passports

I'm about to to leave the UK for Australia, but when I return in a month I'll be entering without any visa documentation as I had to hand it in once I became a UK citizen. But as yet I have not applied for a UK passport. DO I need to bring my original Britsh naturalisation/ citizenship certificate with me to re-enter at the UK border, as I no longer have my unlimited leave to remain UK visa card.

Help!

Comment: Why not apply for a UK passport now?

Comment: @mdewey The application would take 6 weeks, and would involve sending in the citizenship certificate. It's not an options for imminent travel. https://www.passport.service.gov.uk/overseas/information/australia/first/adult/australia

Comment: Why didn't you apply for your passport while applying for citizenship ? That would have taken care of this. I am not sure the airline will allow you to board, but worth a try.

Comment: @DumbCoder Why wouldn't the airline allow an Australian passport holder to board a flight to the UK? If you have an answer which disagrees with mine, you should post it.

Comment: @LMichelle can I find out what happened when you entered UK immigration with your Australian passport and your certificate of naturalisation?

Answer (score 10):

You will have two points at which your documentation is checked. First, your airline will check whether you have the correct documentation for entering the UK. Since you have an Australian passport, you are allowed to travel to the UK visa free. So you are in the clear here.

Once you reach the UK border, it is now your choice how you want to present yourself. Unlike some countries, the UK does not require that its citizens enter the country on a passport which it has issued. However, if you are presenting yourself as a British citizen who intends to remain in the UK indefinitely, you will need to provide evidence. This doesn't need to be a passport. A citizenship certificate will likely make this process very smooth, but it could in principle be anything that can convince the border force officer that you are a British citizen.

If your visit to the UK is short, then you could choose to present yourself as an Australian on a visit, fill out a landing card, and you will likely not face any further scrutiny. However, if the border force officer suspects that you will not comply with the conditions of visa free travel, then you may put yourself in the position of needing to prove that you are a British citizen.

To be safe, you ought to bring your citizenship certificate.

Comment: Thank you so much! That answers my question.I should have applied for a Brit passport earlier, so I will simply take my Citizenship certificate with me to show upon return. Many thanks.

Comment: "you will fill out a landing card": aren't citizens of the UK exempt from that requirement?

Comment: @phoog Yes, of course you are right. I suppose what I meant was that if you don't present yourself as British, you would fill out a landing card.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

I have just gone to Heathrow T2 to pickup the phone on the left and be given a very straight forward answer.

As an Australian who was naturalised on Tuesday, I am allowed to fly out on the Friday with my Australian Passport, BRP and naturalisation certificate and on re entering the UK on Monday, still within the 5 days to send the BRP in they shall take my BRP and confirm my naturalisation and let me in the country.

Why, why did I have to stress and waste hours on the phone and read endless forums.

Comment: So pretty much they told you the same thing that the other answer says?